# Changing object data in javascript of a Django/Heroku website

Tags: javascript, django, heroku

I'm wondering if it's possible for me to change the values of a data object inside my javascript. The javascript receives postmessages from an iframe and I need to be able to store that information to the correct objects, but I'm not quite sure how to do it on the HTML surface or if it's possible to do in the javascript surface.

I can call

```
{{ game.high_score}}
```

in the HTML to fetch the high_score of a certain game object, but my attempts at working out how to have my javascript send values to these objects flies right over my head.

The most recent venture I tried was simply doing

```
game.gameData.name = somevalue;
```

in the javascript, but this doesn't seem to change the global value for this data object value (the change is not seen outside of the javascript).

Are there any solid ways of handling this inside/outside of javascript in Django/Heroku environment?

Edit:

I'm not having trouble at grabbing data from POST: The question might as well be as to how I can change a game object's value when the value I want to change it to stems from javascript.

The game class object I have looks something like this:

```
class GameInstanceDto:
def __init__(self, base: GameIdentityDto, high_score: int, state: str):

    self.base = base,
    self.high_score = high_score,
    self.state = state
```

if I can call the game specific highscore in the HTML with

```
{{ game.high_score }}
```

and I want to alter the value of it in javascript, I personally tried to go with

```
game.high_score = "2500";
```

just to see if the value of the high_score would change, but I didn't see it change at all.

Comment: First to mix several technologies in a project, it is better to learn each one. This is not an issue with django, heroku neither with javascript, it's an issue with your django knowledge. I voted to close just to avoid to downvote your question.

Comment: The current question explanation is really fuzzy to me, but I think it could be edited into being answerable.  Is it that you have a Django model with a view and you are trying to POST data back to your model in the database from the client side in JavaScript?  It would help if you can define/include what this game object is, and full example code of what you have so far.

Comment: Well, the POST method in and of itself is not a problem; I'm able to grab that just fine. What I'm having trouble with is changing the data I have in the scope of javascript to apply to the HTML class object. Let me edit the question a bit

Comment: When you need to update the value of the object, call a view using `AJAX` and send the data in that request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want to POST the changes back to your model or not so let's take it 1 step at a time.

Alter {{ game.high_score }} with JavaScript

```
<div id="high_score">{{ game.high_score }}</div>
<script>
    var high_score = document.getElementByID('high_score');
    high_score.innerHTML = 2500;
</script>
```

Now, it you actually want to send in back as a POST, make element  `high_score` an input field within a form

Comment: It's this simple?! Honest to god I considered doing this exact thing, but instead of taking the 5 minutes to test it I figured it would just change the content of the div into "2500" instead of the value of the object into "2500". I know, a stupid reason, but I had a million other things that I thought sounded more plausible I wanted to test